# How can I display blog category name in URL instead of a static name in Laravel 7?

Tags: laravel

I'm working on my application using Laravel 7, I have done the blog section in my front-end and everything is working well except that I would like to display the URL having name of the category followed by the slug (name of the blog) For example in my URL I would like to have:
[www.domain.com/plumbing/best-plumbing-tips-for-your-home](http://#) instead of [www.domain.com/post/best-plumbing-tips-for-your-home](http://#)

In the second link, "post" is the URL in my web routes file.
"plumbing" is the category "best-plumbing-tips-for-your-home" is the title of the blog and I would like the URL to dynamically pick the name of the Category where the blog post belongs to. Please help.

In my Controller:

```
public function post($slug){
        $post = Post::with('category', 'user')->where('slug', $slug)->first();
        $posts = Post::with('category', 'user')->inRandomOrder()->limit(3)->get();

        $categories = BlogCategory::all();


        if($post){
            return view('blog.front-end.post', compact(['post', 'posts', 'categories']));
        }else {
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }

    public function category($slug){
        $category = BlogCategory::where('slug', $slug)->first();
        if($category){
            $posts = Post::with('category', 'user')->where('category_id', $category->id)->get();
            return view('blog.front-end.category', compact(['category', 'posts']));
        }else {
            return redirect()->route('front-end.home');
        }
    }
```

In my Web Routes file:

```
Route::get('/post/{slug}', 'Blog\FrontEndController@post')->name('front-end.post');
Route::get('/category/{slug}', 'Blog\FrontEndController@category')->name('front-end.category');
Route::get('/blog', 'Blog\FrontEndController@postsForBlogPage')->name('front-end.blog-page');
```

[image]

Comment: maybe https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XxTnuFcOs4I

Comment: @Alberto Sinigaglia Thanks, I already have slugs generated from titles of my posts, what I wanted is to have the name of the category first then followed by the slug. e.g`www.domain.com/mycategoryhere/my-blog-slug-here`

Comment: You must create a route like `Route::get('{section}/{slug}', 'Blog\FrontEndController@post')->name('front-end.post');`

Comment: @ matiaslauriti Thanks, I have tried that but I'm getting an error `Missing required parameters for [Route: front-end.post] [URI: {category}/{slug}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\fundi\resources\views\blog\front-end\blog-page.blade.php)` how can I solve it?